# Prolog : Find the kth element of this list : What's the difference between those 2 implementations?

Tags: prolog

I am playing with some beginner problems in prolog.
"Find the k'th element of a list"   .
I wrote that:

```
kth(X,[X|_],1).
kth(X,[H|R],K):- kth(X,R,K-1).
```

It was **wrong**. Most test-cases resulted into false.
The suggested solution was:

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1).
element_at(X,[_|L],K) :- 
   K > 1, 
   K1 is K - 1, 
   element_at(X,L,K1).
```

Where did my code go wrong? I am interpeting my code as : "if you are looking for the first element it the the head. If you are looking for the kth element in [H|R] it is the (k-1)th element in R ."
even when I tried to include `X>1` in my code, it did not work .

This `K1 is K-1` instead of simply writing `K-1`  inside the function seems like it played a huge role. Can you help me understand?

Answer (score 3):

With `is` you evaluate an arithmetic expression on the right side, unifying it with the left side. In your solution you just apply the term `K-1` in each step. Without it ever being evaluated, `2-1`, `3-1-1`, `4-1-1-1` and so on (length depending on the initial `K`) will not be unifiable with `1` in the base case, and therefore result in `false`.

Comment: "comparing" should be replaced with "unifying": `X is 2-1,X=1.` succeeds but so does `1 is 2-1.` For "arithmetic comparison", there is `=:=`:  `7-1 =:= 2*3.` succeeds.

Comment: Also, the predicate fails not because "in the second recursion step there is no pattern that can be matched" (at least not in general) but because the base case never succeeds in unifying `1` with the constructed term `N-1-1-1....-1`. This can be seen by calling `trace,kth(X,[1,2,3],4).` for example. The call to the base case is then `kth(_4702, [], 4-1-1-1)` and this, as `4-1-1-1` is absolutely not `1`, results in a big NOPE.

Comment: Thanks @DavidTonhofer. I updated the answer with your remarks.